# Cycles render was working but now it renders all black

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Working on a project that was rendering fine for many iterations.  Something happened and now it just renders black.  None of the likely causes listed here is the issue, https://gachokistudios.com/why-a-blender-render-result-is-completely-blank-or-black-and-how-to-fix-it/
Not finding anything on this site either.  Things went weird when I had Joined a number of objects and suffered huge memory bloat, so the offending objects were then deleted.  File size is back to normal but I cannot render the image.

I have an HDRI lighting setup and a spotlight. All layers are ON for render.
Looks fine when rendered in viewport. To speed it up I am just rendering a small region but same results with entire image.
[image]
Just black when rendered
[image]

Comment: Seems to be something in my project.  If I delete enough objects it will render again.  I guess the way to solve this is to spend time isolating the bad object.  I've tried all of the 'clean up' stuff.  I wish blender could give me a hint as to which object is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one of my geometry node 'Collection Info' objects used to particularize objects seems to have become very large so my scene is now tucked inside one of those geometry objects, where it's hidden from the hdri lighting.  How or why it became very large is a separate issue.  Once I muted the node in the geometry node, the scene is now renderable, not black.  This is also why I had some trouble tracking it down to a specific object - It was a geometry node piece.